# Words for the text found in textbooks

Tags: word-request

I am looking for words that describe the paragraphs of text and information you find in student textbooks or course books. For example, in a Maths book you can expect sections of written words teaching you concepts and explaining how you should go about solving problems. I want to use 'instructions', but felt that's closely related to hands-on work.

I want it to fill the space in the following sentence I wish to express:

"There isn't a lot of ..... in this textbook, just questions followed by more questions."

Comment: Instruction? Lessons?

Comment: I think "lessons" applies the the teaching parts of a text book. First you have the lesson, and following that the quiz/exam/questions to confirm that you understand the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word I would choose is "content", as in "what the book *contains*".

> This book is heavy on **rhetoric** but light on **content**.

= this book *talks* a lot, but not very much of it is *meaningful*.

"Content" is a nice term that covers any kind of material that you feel is significant or informative.